# How to change onion URL

Tags: onion-routing, url

I am well aware of how to generate an onion address with mkp224o, and how it spits out the keys, but how do I then use that new address to replace the old one. Many people have answered questions extremely similar to this one, but all they ever say is how to generate it with mkp224o, not how to implement it.

Comment: please be more specific. Do you need to setup your server to run onion domain? Or you do not know how to redirect traffic from old domain to new one?

Comment: I am setting up a new service, one that only shows the nginx welcome page. I want to configure and finish the Tor half of setting up a hidden service, before I mess with the web server. I asked chat-gpt, and they said (roughly) "When you setup up a hidden service, there are two lines you uncomment in the torrc file, allowing tor to listen on localhost. The first line has the path to a folder. Replace this with the path to you public and private keys." When I did this, my hidden service went offline.